# Find the radius of convergence of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the radius of convergence of the series

$$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=0}\,\dfrac{n(x+2)^n}{3^{n+1}}$$

Can someone help to explain step by step?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let   $\;\;\;a_n=\dfrac{n(x+2)^n}{3^{n+1}}$

$$a_{n+1}=\dfrac{(n+1)\,(x+2)^{n+1}}{3^{n+2}}$$
By the ratio test
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\,\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=L<1$$
then the series converges.
$$\therefore\,\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\dfrac{\dfrac{(n+1)\,(x+2)^{n+1}}{3^{{n+2}}}}{\dfrac{n(x+2)^n}{3^{n+1}}}\right|\\\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\,\left|\,\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\,\left(1+\,\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\dfrac{|x+2|}{3}\\=\dfrac{|x+2|}{3}$$
If $\;\;\dfrac{|x+2|}{3}<1$  then series converges.

If $\;\;\dfrac{|x+2|}{3}>1$   then series diverges.

So it converges if $\;|x+2|<3$ and diverges if $\;|x+2|>3$

Radius of convergence is $\;R=3$

Answer (score 0):

With root test 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|\dfrac{n(x+2)^n}{3^{n+1}}|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt[n]{n}|x+2|}{3^{1+\frac1n}}=\dfrac{|x+2|}{3}<1$$
shows $-5<x<1$. Also for $x=1$ and $x=-5$ the series clearly diverges.